# C program - else without a previous if error

Tags: c

I cannot see what I am missing that is throwing the else without an if error.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?  What am I missing that it doesn't see the if that it is obviously looking for?  I am working to create a guessing number program that creates a random number and then asks the user to enter a number that the program reads and lets the user know if it is too high or low or if they guessed it right.  Once the guess the right number, it should print out they guessed it with the number of guesses.  I am currently hung up on the missing else without previous if error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>




int main() {

    int guess;
    time_t t;
    int randNumber;
    int numberOfGuess = 0;


    /*srand is used to seed the random number so that it is different every time.  This is giving the
    random number an initial base that the rand() can use to offset with a random number.*/
    srand(time(&t));

    //This will give a number between 0 and 19, so the +1 makes the number 1 through 20.
    randNumber = (rand()% 19) +1;

    printf("Let's play a guessing game and see how many times it takes you to guess a preselected ");
    printf("random number between 1 - 20.\n");
    printf("Please guess a number between 1 and 20:\t", guess);
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    //The next statement increases the number of guesses by one
    numberOfGuess++;

    /*This sets the while loop to validate if the guess is not the randNumber, which enables an escape once
    the guess is equal to the randNumber*/
    while (guess != randNumber){

    //If the guess is the randNumber, then I added a break to allow the program to complete.
    if (guess == randNumber) {
        break;
    }

    /*If the guess is lower than or equal to 0 or the guess is greater than 20, I print out the statement
    letting the user know the number wasn't between the number and to enter a new guess*/
    else {
        if (guess <= 0 || guess > 20)
        printf("\nThe number guessed isn't between 1 and 20, please enter a new guess:\t");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        }

    /*If the guess in higher than the randNumber, I let the user know and ask the user to
    enter another guess */
    else {
        if(guess > randNumber) {
            printf("\nYour guess of %d is too high, guess again:\t", guess);
            scanf("%d", &guess);
          }

        /*If the guess is lower that the randNumber, I let the user know and ask the user to
        enter another guess*/
        else {
            if(guess < randNumber) {
                printf("\nYour guess of %d is too low, guess again:\t", guess);
                scanf("%d", &guess);
            }

            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nYou guessed it, the number was %d and it took you %d guesses!", guess, numberOfGuess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line gives an error?

Comment: Running your code through a formatting tool like `clang-format` might help. Your indentation is pretty confusing as-is.

Comment: It's the line just after `/* If the guess is higher... */` comment.   Maintaining careful indentation would have probably helped track this down.

Comment: Missing `{` after `if (guess <= 0 || guess > 20)`

Comment: The bracket was the issue,, ugh!  One more thing please, now the program is running but the count is off by one and after I make two guesses it tells me I am right even if I am not.  For example, I entered 10 and then it said it was too low, so I entered 9 and then it said I guessed it and says the number is the 2nd number I entered and that it took me one guess.  I need it to make me keep guessing until I select the random number, what did I miss please?

Comment: @AnnetteKitz - consider breaking the main loop into separate parts: at the top of the loop, prompt for input, validate that input, and only then increment your guess count. If the user didn't enter a number (if `scanf()` returns other than 1), if the guess is out of the 1..20 range, use `continue` to start the loop over. THEN, once you have a known-valid guess, increment your count and do your match/too-low/too-high test.  Mixing input-prompting in the middle of code logic is typically confusing and a source of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program contains this:

```
if (guess == randNumber) {
    ...
}
...
else {
    ...
    }
...
else {
    ...
    }
```

So you have two `else` clauses after just one `if`.

Compare where you have braces (`{ ... }`) to where you want braces.